# How to know if any of the cell of Excel sheets contains formula fields

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel file with tens of sheets. I want to convert all the cells to "value" fields. I can do this by copy-paste manually, but I want to know what are the fields generated using formulas, especially `vlookup`, `concatenate`, `round` etc.

Comment: You can try to show formula in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe "Show formulas" from the "formulas" tab could help you.

If you want to change all of your formulas to values that the formulas return just copy whole sheet and paste it with pasting option "just text" (right mouse button).

Answer (score 1):

This VBA will loop through all sheets and convert all formulas to values:

```
For Each mySht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    mySht.UsedRange.Value = mySht.UsedRange.Value
Next mySht
```

I recommend you try this on a copy of your file

Answer (score 0):

If [ISFORMULA()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISFORMULA-function-E4D1355F-7121-4EF2-801E-3839BFD6B1E5) function is available for your excel version. then you can use it.

If not, you may try :

```
=IFERROR(IF(FORMULATEXT(A1)<>"","A formula",""),"NOT a formula")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: ISFORMULA() can be used for conditional formatting by formula. It can be more visual.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Should I check each column one by one ?

Comment: hurm... seems like @Akina 's solution suits your need better. || if your're just looking for the `vlookup` function.. just press Ctrl + F and find vlooup will do.

Comment: @p._phidot_ Yea. Ctrl + F , so simple